# Organize a excel sheet with a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a really big Excel sheet with 2000 rows.

In the sheet I have names and next to the name a lot of "NO" and one "YES".

Each column has a different name.

I want to have a macro which automatically give me a sheet with the name and next to the name the name of the columns in which I have a "YES".

For example:

```
Name     A    B    C    D
God      NO   NO   YES  NO
Gosch    YES  NO   NO   NO
Josch    NO   YES  NO   NO
ME       NO   NO   YES  NO
```

Should look like:

Name

```
God    C
Gosch  A
Josch  B
ME     C
```

Comment: You can loop through your lines&columns thanks to two for statements... Or you can also use one for to loop through the lines and use the method "find" to find the "YES" on each lines

Comment: Because you only have about 2000 rows, you could just use the `MATCH` and `INDEX` Excel functions and thus avoid VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to your data sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4") 'change Sheet4 to your output sheet

    With srcSht
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row    'last row in source sheet using column A
        destSht.Cells(1, 1) = "Name"
        destSht.Cells(1, 2) = "Column"
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            destSht.Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)      'enter name in output sheet
            destSht.Cells(i, 2) = .Evaluate("=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(""YES"",B" & i & ":E" & i & ",0))")   'enter column name in output sheet
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You can do this easily using formula as below.
Enter the following formula in `Cell G2`

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,1,MATCH("YES",B2:E2,0))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]